# How to pause and stop when uses Papa.parse streaming reading in react?

Tags: reactjs, state-management, papaparse

How to do the streaming data reading in virtual list? When user scrolls to bottom will resume the the chunk download and paused in each chunk callback

From the docs streaming parsing only can stop and resume inside step/chunk and complete callback? how to control it outside of the callback?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.